# java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION Google Play Android 10

Tags: java, android

Any device using Android 10 is getting this error when installing my game.
This happened after i upgrade my API level from 26 to 28.
Devices using Android 9 and below dont have any problem.
What can it be causing this? Maybe extra permission needed in manifest? Couldnt find anything in my documentation.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-9]
Caused by
  at com.google.ads.conversiontracking.e.a 
  at com.google.ads.conversiontracking.e$b.run 
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

Manifest is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="28" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="9" android:installLocation="auto" package="origin.dragon.free.game.rpg.mmorpg" platformBuildVersionCode="29" platformBuildVersionName="9" android:versionCode="7800" android:versionName="7.80.00">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.zythegds.beta.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="v26.revengemu.com"/>
                <data android:host="com.zythegds.beta" android:scheme="kunlun"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="tmsk_platname" android:value="ZYTHE"/>
        <meta-data android:name="tmsk_sdkname" android:value="ZYTHE"/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kunlun.location" android:value="ph-en"/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kunlun.productId" android:value="1021"/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kunlun.unionId" android:value=""/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kunlun.unionSid" android:value=""/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kunlun.gameCode" android:value="eyJ2Ijoia2wifQ%3D%3D"/>
        <meta-data android:name="Kunlun.debugMode" android:value="false"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.kunlun.platform.android.KunlunReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.kunlun.platform.android.KunlunActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.ads.conversiontracking.InstallReceiver">
            <inner-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </inner-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
          android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is that the *complete* stacktrace and exception message?  It looks like some of it is missing.

Comment: java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-9]
Unity version     : 5.2.2f1
Device model      : OnePlus GM1913
Device fingerprint: OnePlus/OnePlus7Pro_EEA/OnePlus7Pro:10/QKQ1.190716.003/1911070200:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at com.google.ads.conversiontracking.e.a (SourceFile:211)
  at com.google.ads.conversiontracking.e$b.run (SourceFile:173)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)

Comment: Put it in the question please.   Are you sure that there is nothing between "Caused by" and "at"?  (It appears to be saying that an exception without a class name was the cause ...)

Comment: Nothing, check http://prntscr.com/qg75a7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this problem, google requests from APi28+ (android9+) to add this into manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Thank you all for your time and effort.